# Inserting rows into Oracle database without getting duplicate key error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written the following script in order to insert multiple rows based on a match criteria:

```
Insert
Into RATE_HEADER_NEGOTIATED (RESORT, RATE_CODE, NAME_ID, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE,
  INSERT_USER, INSERT_DATE, UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, ORDER_BY)
(SELECT 'HRHLC','ST20B',NAME_ID,'01-JAN-2016','12-FEB-2016',
   '327','12-FEB-2016','327','12-FEB-2016','1'
from rate_header_negotiated
where resort = 'HRHLC'
and RATE_CODE = 'ST20BL'
and RATE_CODE <> 'ST20B'
and END_DATE >= '01-JAN-16');
```

My problem is it is giving me duplicate key errors because there are already lines containing 'ST20B' - I need to fix that part of my script so it only inserts rows on lines that do not contain that ST20BThe script works if I manually delete the duplicate lines before running it.

Comment: Well what is the primary key?  Please show the table definition and all unique constraints.

Comment: Don't rely on your NLS settings and implicit date conversion; use `to_date('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, or a date literal like `DATE '2016-01-01'`. You also seem to be passing numbers as strings. What is the primary/unique key for the table?

Comment: The Primary Unique Key is the NAME_ID column it is an identifier for each individual profile. So basically I want to take the profiles that contain ST20BL and duplicate that line but insert ST20B. However some of those NAME_ID do have the ST20B already

Comment: That's the entire key? Your insert is using the selected `name_id`, so if you delete those it won't find or insert anything. Are you sure it isn't on both name_id and rate_code?

Comment: Apologies, Yes if you put it that way if I dont put in RESORT, RATE_CODE and NAME_ID nothing will enter. If I go and remove the profiles that cause the duplication, the above code works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If the first of these conditions is true, the second must be as well, so it's redundant:

```
and RATE_CODE = 'ST20BL'
and RATE_CODE <> 'ST20B'
```

You seem to want to exclude those with a row with that value already, so you need a `not exists` clause:

```
insert into RATE_HEADER_NEGOTIATED (RESORT, RATE_CODE, NAME_ID, BEGIN_DATE,
  END_DATE,INSERT_USER, INSERT_DATE, UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, ORDER_BY)
select 'HRHLC', 'ST20B', NAME_ID, DATE '2016-01-01',
  DATE '2016-02-12', 327, DATE '2016-02-12', 327, DATE '2016-02-12', 1
from rate_header_negotiated rhn
where RESORT = 'HRHLC'
and RATE_CODE = 'ST20BL'
and END_DATE >= DATE '2016-01-01'
and not exists (
  select null
  from rate_header_negotiated
  where RESORT = rhn.RESORT
  and NAME_ID = rhn.NAME_ID
  and RATE_CODE = 'ST20B'
  -- any other key columns
);
```

You could also do a left join or not-in but not-exists is fairly easy to understand I think.

From Oracle 11gR2 you can [use the IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX  hint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/whatsnew.htm#BGGHBJAA) instead of checking for the key's existence. You may prefer that, or may prefer to make it clear that you expect and want to avoid the existing records. It's also possible to record the errors but it seems like you don't need that here.

I've also changed to use date literals so you are not rely on implicit conversions or session NLS settings, and removed what appear to be incorrect single-quotes around numbers, on the assumption the table columns those go into are number types - thus avoiding further implicit conversion.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you very much for the above, I did give it a try and its kicking out the following error still:   Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (OPERA.RATE_HEADER_NEG_UK) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Comment: RATE_HEADER_NEG_UK is the key on (RESORT, RATE_CODE, NAME_ID)? Adding the DDL for the table and all its keys/indexes would be helpful.

Comment: There isn't a table called that anyway so I am not sure where the error is coming from. I am more trained in extraction than inserting

Comment: RATE_HEADER_NEG_UK is the constraint name, not a table name; from the UK part presumably a unique constraint rather than a primary key. Look in `all_cons_columns` to see which columns is covers. Or use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` to get the table creation statement and constraint/index creation statements.